# Copy a file into a Folder with timestamp

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I'm stuck now with following problem. (i googled but didn't find a solution for that)

The thing is i want to copy a file in to a folder with a variable in the name of the folder. The variable is a timestamp. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
datetime_ordner = time.strftime("__%d_%m_%y-%H-%M")
dir = mkdir('test' + str(datetime_ordner))
data_xls = pd.read_excel('test.xls')
data_xls.to_csv('test_daten' + str(datetime) + '.csv')
shutil.copy2('test_daten.csv', '/',dir(),'test' + str(datetime) + '.csv')
```

I tried it ofer shutil but it wont work. I'm sorry if this may be a stupid question but I couldn't figure it out on myself.

Comment: You should always include the actual, full error message so we can help you more easily.

Comment: shutil.copy2('test_daten.csv', '/',dir(),'test' + str(datetime) + '.csv')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Thats the error i get!

Comment: That tells you that you tried to execute the call operator `()` on an object that does not provide it. There's three candidates in that line. As a hint, check what the mkdir function's return value is.

Comment: do to use dir as a variable name dir is a built in function in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 0):

For copy file in a folder with time stamp you need to do string formatting for your path.
Here is the solution for you..

```
import time
import os
import shutil

# CREATE DATA TIME VARIABLE
datetime_var = time.strftime("__%d_%m_%y-%H-%M")

# THIS IS SOURCE FILE
src_file = r'D:\source.txt'

# LETS CREATE DESTINATION FILE WITH DATE TIME NAME
dst_file = r'D:\{}\{}.txt'.format(datetime_var, datetime_var)
file_path = dst_file.split(os.path.basename(dst_file))[0]
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.makedirs(file_path)

# COPY FILE 
shutil.copy2(src_file, dst_file)
```